# (Node) Getting HTML from GET when data is streaming

Tags: html, node.js, ajax, http

I'm using Node. On server side, I got requests from clients. Before sending response to the client, I'm fetching data from other web sites so I'm creating a request object using request npm module.
Basically I have something like this :

```
request(url, (req,resp) => {...});
```

The problem is with some pages it's dynamic. Think about something like facebook, when you scroll down  the page with your mouse => new data is coming and the HTML code is becoming bigger and bigger.

The problem with the HTML data I got back from `resp` object in mycallback function is that it only has very little data.

With a browser I can get more data by scrolling down the page but is it possible to get all data programatically ?

Thank you ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
request(url, (req,resp) => {...})
.on('complete', (data) => {
  console.log(data.body);
});
```

Or 
let bufferedData = '';

```
on('data', (data) => {
  bufferedData += data.toString();
})
```